# Android -store a list of around 1000 statements. File vs SQLite

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to store a list of 1000 lines which i will write to an array when activity starts. No queries. Just need to rewrite the *entire* list on some condition and always display the *entire* list. As SQLite is also only a file , i was wondering what performace benefits does writing a file to storage have over it , if any.
Basically what cases should we use file over SQLite? I know a case - when the data cannot be written in form of table. but if its possible to write data in a table (like a single list) which will then be saved to an array then is file still better.

Comment: Show what you want to put on the lines.

Answer (score 0):

There are two couple of things both Files system and SQLite introduced in android for storage techniques we can say about each as follows

Files:When you want to store a bunch of data in your application in serialized object format you can store it in to file and save to disc,once after you can deserialize and retrieve data what you want it from

SQLite: It we can use accordingly along with file system but as it have tables we can consider this approach for populating listviews withe limited content(metadata)

For example :You are storing an Object class in to file it might be have large data in it as its not possible/not good an approach to store in db(SQLite) we can store metadata(such as file name what we are storing in file system).

Hence with metadata we can populate listview with SQLite db,and once list is populated with file names we can retrieve respective file from the local storage.

And we have a CursorAdapter in android which will helpful to create a listview with cursor reference.

For your question its bit memory consumption to populate a listview from the file system as there are too many files in storage.More over if it is SQLite data base as we have cursor reference with query we can populate listview using CursonAdapter